# Google Photos - Cannot turn on backup

Tags: sync, google, crashes, google-photos

I have a Yu Yureka mobile with stock CM12.1. It came preinstalled with Google Photos and I updated it to its latest version. It was working fine until one day I tried to free up space by deleting already synced photos using the app itself. It crashed. After that whenever I open the app, it crashes within 5 seconds.

I tried [several workarounds](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/photos/dy5RpbW4r3w) like clearing the cache, data of Photos, clearing Google Play Services' data, manually turning backup photos off and on but nothing works.

**[a]** Finally I uninstalled the update and arrived at the stock version of Photos. Now the app is not crashing immediately but I cannot turn on backup. It is always disabled. Whenever I click the Backup button in Settings (of Photos), it opens Backup screen for a moment but then closes and arrives back at the Settings menu.

After this, I installed the latest update but then again, the cycle repeats.

Can you guys help me in solving this issue? I tried putting reviews and reported bugs, but you know, it's Google.

I took a log of the Backup window closing event I mentioned in **[a]**. I cleared the logcat just before I pressed the Backup button -> logcat is on -> Backup window closes -> logcat is off. Here's it:

```
--------- beginning of main
I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ104 from CPU5 to CPU4
I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ177 from CPU5 to CPU4
--------- beginning of system
I/ActivityManager(  769): START u0 {cmp=com.google.android.gms/.photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsActivity} from uid 10017 on display 0
W/ActivityManager(  769): startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent { cmp=com.google.android.gms/.photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsActivity }
V/WindowManager(  769): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{89d066e token=Token{30d029e9 ActivityRecord{3c721270 u0 com.google.android.gms/.photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsActivity t122}}} to stack=1 task=122 at 0
V/WindowManager(  769): Adding window Window{19a2d21 u0 Starting com.google.android.gms} at 4 of 7 (after Window{26d33434 u0 com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.home.HomeActivity})
D/ChimeraActivityProxy(17075): Loading activity implementation for ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsActivity}
D/ChimeraActivityProxy(17075): Proxying container activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsActivity} to Chimera activity impl .photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsChimeraActivity
I/art     (  769): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 87190(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 11(220KB) LOS objects, 5% free, 36MB/38MB, paused 4.679ms total 126.710ms
V/WindowManager(  769): Adding window Window{178abbff u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.gms.photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsActivity} at 4 of 8 (before Window{19a2d21 u0 Starting com.google.android.gms})
I/ActivityManager(  769): Displayed com.google.android.gms/.photos.autobackup.ui.AutoBackupSettingsActivity: +506ms
I/Timeline(15097): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2ce0c0f6 time:17592408
I/Timeline(  769): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{32b2d99e u0 com.google.android.apps.photos/.home.HomeActivity t103} time:17592990
W/ResourceType( 1225): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
W/PackageManager( 1225): Failure retrieving resources for com.google.android.gms: Resource ID #0x0
E/GpsXtraDownloader(  769): No XTRA servers were specified in the GPS configuration
I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ178 from CPU5 to CPU7
D/TaskPersister(  769): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=121_task.xml
D/TaskPersister(  769): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=121_task_thumbnail.png
I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ104 from CPU4 to CPU7
```

---

**UPDATE:** I updated the app again to latest version and the backup didn't work again. Assistant was showing "Waiting for sync" always. But then I deleted the unsynced photos from my camera folder and viola! Sync came back on and everything was good.

But today, I tried to sync a jpg and mp4 file and it synced correctly. But then I tried to play the synced video in Photos itself and it crashed. It is now crashing everytime I open the app. I took another log of this crash:

```
--------- beginning of crash

F/libc    (32081): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x10102464c457f in tid 32224 (Thread-1191)

I/libc    (32081): Suppressing debuggerd output because prctl(PR_GET_DUMPABLE)==0

W/InputDispatcher(  775): channel '124051c6 com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.home.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9

E/InputDispatcher(  775): channel '124051c6 com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.home.HomeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

I/WindowState(  775): WIN DEATH: Window{124051c6 u0 com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.home.HomeActivity}

W/InputDispatcher(  775): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '124051c6 com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.apps.photos.home.HomeActivity (server)'

D/ConnectivityService(  775): ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ id=67, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ], android.os.BinderProxy@2462edca)

D/ConnectivityService(  775): releasing NetworkRequest NetworkRequest [ id=67, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]

I/Zygote  (  314): Process 32081 exited due to signal (11)

I/ActivityManager(  775): Process com.google.android.apps.photos (pid 32081) has died

E/ConnectivityService(  775): RemoteException caught trying to send a callback msg for NetworkRequest [ id=67, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]

I/UPNPSearch(29931): Destroying...

I/AirPlayProvider(29931): Destroying...

W/ActivityManager(  775): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.photos/.camerashortcut.ForegroundServiceImpl in 1000ms

W/ActivityManager(  775): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.photos/com.google.android.libraries.social.async.BackgroundTaskService in 11000ms

W/ActivityManager(  775): Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.apps.photos/.dbprocessor.impl.DatabaseProcessorService in 11000ms

W/ActivityManager(  775): Force removing ActivityRecord{3a9609ec u0 com.google.android.apps.photos/.home.HomeActivity t67}: app died, no saved state

I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ174 from CPU4 to CPU6

W/MdnsClient_Cast(29876): Multicast lock held. Releasing. Subtypes:"96084372"

W/MdnsClient(29876): unicast receiver thread is already dead.

W/InputMethodManagerService(  775): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 32081 uid 10075

I/Timeline( 1712): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@9944138 time:8891311

I/Timeline(  775): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{24e8a89e u0 com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet/com.android.launcher3.Launcher t1} time:8891571

I/ActivityManager(  775): Start proc 32272:com.google.android.apps.photos/u0a75 for service com.google.android.apps.photos/.camerashortcut.ForegroundServiceImpl

I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ104 from CPU4 to CPU6

W/GCM-DMM ( 2113): broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.google.android.apps.photos (has extras) }

E/SQLiteLog(32272): (283) recovered 4 frames from WAL file /data/data/com.google.android.apps.photos/databases/gphotos0.db-wal

W/linker  (32272): /data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-1/lib/arm64/libcronet.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6ffffffe arg 0x2fc0

W/linker  (32272): /data/app/com.google.android.apps.photos-1/lib/arm64/libcronet.so: unused DT entry: type 0x6fffffff arg 0x3

I/art     (32272): Note: end time exceeds epoch: 

D/ConnectivityService(  775): listenForNetwork for NetworkRequest [ id=68, legacyType=-1, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED] ]

D/ConnectivityService(  775): handleRegisterNetworkRequest checking NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 103]

D/ConnectivityService(  775): apparently satisfied.  currentScore=60

D/ConnectivityManager.CallbackHandler(32272): CM callback handler got msg 524290

I/art     (32272): Note: end time exceeds epoch: 

I/art     (32272): Note: end time exceeds epoch: 

I/art     (32272): Note: end time exceeds epoch: 

W/WakefulBroadcastReceiver(32272): No active wake lock id #1

I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ178 from CPU4 to CPU6

I/ActivityManager(  775): Start proc 32331:com.cyanogenmod.filemanager/u0a39 for service com.cyanogenmod.filemanager/.providers.secure.SecureCacheCleanupService

W/FileManagerApplication(32331): Command /system/xbin/su not found. Exists: false; IsFile: false.

W/IntentService[A(32351): type=1400 audit(0.0:840): avc: denied { read } for name="mem" dev="debugfs" ino=237346 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[A(32351): type=1400 audit(0.0:841): avc: denied { read } for name="mem" dev="debugfs" ino=237346 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debugfs:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/ActivityManager(  775): getRunningAppProcesses: caller 10095 does not hold REAL_GET_TASKS; limiting output

V/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): onHandleIntent(Intent { act=com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.ACTION_START_INDEX cmp=com.cyanogenmod.filemanager/.service.MimeTypeIndexService (has extras) })

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): Action: com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.ACTION_START_INDEX

V/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): performIndexAction(/storage/emulated/0)

I/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): Starting mime type usage indexing on '/storage/emulated/0'

I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ131 from CPU4 to CPU6

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): AUDIO = 11108680

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): TEXT = 142203

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): BINARY = 6825

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): FONT = 187236

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): DATABASE = 48

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): VIDEO = 288993908

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): COMPRESS = 34672032

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): DOCUMENT = 13951531

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): EBOOK = 683804

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): NONE = 352704314

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): IMAGE = 50246484

V/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): onHandleIntent(Intent { act=com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.ACTION_START_INDEX cmp=com.cyanogenmod.filemanager/.service.MimeTypeIndexService (has extras) })

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): Action: com.cyanogenmod.filemanager.ACTION_START_INDEX

V/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): performIndexAction(/system)

I/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): Starting mime type usage indexing on '/system'

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:842): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/adsprpcd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=247 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:adsprpcd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:843): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/audiod" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=256 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:audiod_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:844): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/auditd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=257 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:logd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:845): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/bootanimation" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=261 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:bootanim_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:846): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/btnvtool" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=262 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:bluetooth_loader_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:847): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/clatd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=269 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:clatd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:848): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/debuggerd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=279 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debuggerd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:849): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/debuggerd64" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=280 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:debuggerd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:850): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/dhcpcd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=283 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:dhcp_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:851): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/dnsmasq" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=285 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:dnsmasq_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:852): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/drmserver" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=287 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:drmserver_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:853): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/dumpstate" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=289 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:dumpstate_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:854): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/hostapd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=304 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:hostapd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:855): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/install-recovery.sh" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=312 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:install_recovery_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:856): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/installd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=313 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:installd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:857): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/irsc_util" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=319 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:irsc_util_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:858): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/keystore" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=320 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:keystore_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:859): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/lmkd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=324 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:lmkd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:860): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/location-mq" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=327 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:location_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:861): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/logd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=330 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:logd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:862): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/mdnsd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=337 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mdnsd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:863): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/mediaserver" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=339 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mediaserver_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:864): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/mm-pp-daemon" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=345 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mm-pp-daemon_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:865): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/mm-qcamera-daemon" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=346 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mm-qcamerad_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:866): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/msm_irqbalance" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=350 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:msm_irqbalanced_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:867): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/mtpd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=351 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:mtp_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:868): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/ndc" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=354 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:wcnss_service_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:869): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/netd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=356 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:870): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/netmgrd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=357 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:netmgrd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

W/IntentService[M(32366): type=1400 audit(0.0:871): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/system/bin/perfd" dev="mmcblk0p25" ino=366 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:perfd_exec:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

I/art     (32331): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 16.140ms for cause HomogeneousSpaceCompact

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): AUDIO = 15364648

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): EXEC = 5424

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): TEXT = 2903462

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): BINARY = 492086588

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): FONT = 30253716

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): COMPRESS = 19015425

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): APP = 566877958

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): NONE = 330889839

D/MimeTypeIndexService(32331): IMAGE = 7799486

I/ActivityManager(  775): Killing 31076:com.cyngn.fota/u0a5 (adj 15): empty #17

I/MSM-irqbalance(  279): Decided to move IRQ130 from CPU4 to CPU6
```

Comment: I got a badge for this being an unpopular question. :P Does anybody know a solution to this?